# What would make a Wordpress site display the front-end but not the back-end?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm stumped and looking for some ideas. I have several Wordpress + Woocomm sites I built and manage for a client. Recently, it was reported that they couldn't login to manage orders or users. I am able to login, see the entire front end, add order to cart etc. However, as soon as I go to dashboard to view the back-end, it's completely busted.

[front-end screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyktQ.png)

[Back-end screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRQTA.png)

Initially, I thought auto-update, plugin conflict, etc. I took all the usual steps but here's where it gets strange. I have multiple different sites on this host server including a dev and stage instances, all different versions of wordpress or woocomm and some with auto updates enabled and some without. Each and every site has the same exact issue happening out of nowhere. Even the instances that had not been touched for 9 months.

When I pull up the console panel on the malformed, busted dashboard, they are reporting either jQuery not defined, or a core wp script that's not defined. Selecting an unstyled option like "themes" or "updates" triggers a custom 404. This is bizarre so any suggestions are appreciated.

Let me know what additional info or screenshots would be helpful to your sleuthing.

Comment: "it's completely busted", What do you exactly mean with that?. "jQuery not defined, or a core wp script that's not defined" Do you have any backup? I'm not an expert, but It seems some files got corrupted. Have you tried seeing the logs?

Comment: Hey syntax, I added some screenshots. Given that this suddenly happened to multiple sites on the same host server, what's the likelihood of every instance suddenly having a corrupt file? Especially since many instances haven't been touched for months. Good tip on the log, I'll look into them but this is certainly something I've never come across before.

Comment: Did you or someone (maybe automated) make and server changes or updates?

Comment: Hi Dan, great question. I did look for that. No changes on my end. I went into cPanel and checked PHP versions. Everything was fine and I couldn't detect any changes. I pulled log files as Syntax_Error mentioned. All that was in there was some warnings on deprecated syntax that I previously resolved through WP_DEBUG. It's the strangest thing. What would make your front end run fine, your dashboard break and return 404's on any admin option + trigger console errors that dependencies are not loaded? The front-end relies on the same exact dependencies (e.g. jQuery) and works fine. Strange!!